# Boostrap Css - Add icon right and align side with text size is different

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need your help for an issue I want to create some button with the same size (no matter of the text) and add the arrow icon on the right corner of the button. 
But the arrow is not align with the other button because the number of caracters of the text. 
I am using bootstrap here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="item" style="text-align: center">
        <a class="btn btn-programs" style="width:230px" href="#">My 1st button with longer text<span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
      </div>
</p>
<div class="item" style="text-align: center">
        <a class="btn btn-programs" style="width:230px" href="#">My 2nd Button <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
      </div>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the class

> btn-block

```
 <a class="btn btn-programs btn-block" href="#">My 1st button<span class="btn-label btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following css to your page

```
    .item a span.btn-label
  {
    float: right;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but the text will be on the right and it is very ugly :s

Comment: I found the solution I just have to do float: right on the <span> and it is working fine :) Thanks All !